# java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before notify()

Tags: java, android

//I gets data from data handler class from sq-lite database.

```
public class ReminderReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
List<Reminder> reminderList;
Date dateobj = new Date();
```

//Call method to get list from sqlite

```
new DataBaseHandler(context).getAllReminderList();
reminderList = Util.reminderList;
for (int i = 0; i < reminderList.size(); i++) {
Reminder reminder = reminderList.get(i);
if (df.format(dateobj).equalsIgnoreCase(reminder.getDatetime())) {
try {
     new DataBaseHandler(context).deleteReminder(reminder.getTaskid());
     Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, TaskDetail.class);
     intent1.putExtra("id", reminder.getTaskid());
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1,                                  intent1, 0);
   String taskName = reminder.getTaskname();
```

//Showing notification

```
   NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)                                                   context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  Uri alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
  if (alert == null) {
       alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
                }
   Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
   NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)                    context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
 Notification myNotication;
 builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.st);
 builder.setContentTitle("SharedTasklist Notification");
builder.setTicker("SharedTasklist Reminder");
builder .setContentText("It's time to do " + taskName);
builder .setAutoCancel(true);
builder .setOngoing(true);
builder .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
builder .setSound(alert); //This sets the sound to play
builder.build();
builder.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
myNotication = builder.getNotification();
Random random = new Random();
int m = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;
manager.notify(m, myNotication);
```

// I check all other classes and it's all right. Here it shows error that object not locked thread before notifying..

```
   alert.notify();
                 }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```